# Convert String to Date in Powershell

Tags: powershell, date, datetime

Today I met a problem with the conversion of this type of string "8/3/2020 10:29:33 AM" which I need to convert to date format.

I try this type of command and get an error every time:

```bsh
$PwdExpiracy = "8/3/2020 10:29:33 AM"
$date = [datetime]::ParseExact($PwdExpiracy,'MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss tt',$null)
```

The error is :

```bsh
Exception calling "ParseExact" with "3" argument(s): "String was not recognized as a valid DateTime."
Au caractère Ligne:1 : 1
+ $date = [datetime]::ParseExact($PwdExpiracy,'MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss tt',$nu ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : FormatException
```

Could you help me with this ? That would be very kind of you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're using format specifiers for dates with leading zeroes and 24-hour time - change to the following:

```bsh
$date = [datetime]::ParseExact($PwdExpiracy, 'M/d/yyyy hh:mm:ss tt', $null)
```

- `M` is the month *without* leading zeroes
- `d` is the day *without* leading zeroes
- `hh` is the hour in 12-hour time (`AM`/`PM`)

---

If you still receive `"String was not recognized as a valid DateTime."`, try forcing `ParseExact()` to use the `InvariantCulture` (roughly equivalent to `en-US` locale), and it should accept it:

```bsh
$date = [datetime]::ParseExact($PwdExpiracy, 'M/d/yyyy hh:mm:ss tt', [cultureinfo]::InvariantCulture)
```

Answer (score 0):

[Mathias R. Jessen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/712649/mathias-r-jessen) said in [a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61208082/convert-string-to-date-in-powershell/62325536#comment108281602_61208216):

> The exact same `"String was not recognized as a valid DateTime."`.
>
> Can you try:
>
> ```
> [datetime]::ParseExact($PwdExpiracy,'M/d/yyyy hh:mm:ss tt',[cultureinfo]::InvariantCulture)
> ```

which worked for me.